# JSDate: check if given unix timestamp is in seconds or milliseconds

Tags: javascript, date

I want to check in VanillaJS if a unix timestamp is in milliseconds or in seconds, are there some lightweight solution in VanillaJS.

Comment: Only if you have an idea of a valid date range.

Comment: @pilchard yeah that's the problem. I think I should just check if the date divided by thousand is closer to "now" than if I don't divide it or something like that. So there is no real solution for that, that's unfortunate but I already thought that :/

Comment: Likely any time value less than 31500000000 (milliseconds in one year) is seconds, so `if (timeValue < 3.15e10)` then it's *probably* seconds (or a millisecond time value before 1 Jan 1971).

Answer (score 2):

Ok, you can't set the timespan, that is now calculated by which is closer to "now".

```js
const date = new Date(timestamp);

if (Math.abs(Date.now() - date) < Math.abs(Date.now() - date * 1000)) {
   console.log("milliseconds");
} else {
   console.log("seconds");
}
```

Comment: What you're doing is comparing time values, so converting *timestamp* to a *Date* is entirely redundant. `Math.abs(Date.now() - timestamp)` will give an identical result.

Comment: @RobG oh yeah, I used that because my the function I used before needed that, because I also converted the date to a string. In this case it is truly useless, redundant. Do you think it impact performance?

Comment: I think the performance difference would be truely negligible. :-)

Answer (score 1):

How about this? This can verify if timestamp in milliseconds is valid or not

```
function isTimestampMsValid(timestampMs) {
  timestampMs = parseInt(timestampMs);
  let minTimestampMs = new Date("1971").getTime();
  // getTime() method of Date object returns the stored time value
  // in milliseconds since midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC.
  let maxTimestampMs = new Date(
    "" + (new Date().getUTCFullYear() + 100)
  ).getTime();
  return timestampMs > minTimestampMs && timestampMs < maxTimestampMs;
}
```

With this, you can even verify timestamp in seconds and microseconds.

To verify if timestamp in seconds is valid:

```
isTimestampMsValid(timestampS * 1000)
```

For timestamp in microseconds:

```
isTimestampMsValid(timestampMicro / 1000)
```